# LUKS: encrypting swap without requiring a passphrase on boot?

Tags: lvm, luks, dmcrypt

I have a setup where I have a logical volume (`data`) that should be LUKS-encrypted. However, my feeling is that the rest of the filesystem shouldn't be encrypted, which gives some advantages:

1. The `data` LV doesn't need to be mounted until it's required, so the system can boot without the user manually entering a passphrase (this is a VPS: there's no TPM/etc)
2. Possible performance improvement
3. The system can auto-reboot after security updates

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any point encrypting the `data` LV if I don't also encrypt the `swap` partition. If `swap` is encrypted, then it has to be opened/started at boot time anyway, and the user must then enter a passphrase.

Is there any way around this? In other words, how do I secure an LV without forcing the user to enter a passphrase at boot?

Comment: You can give SWAP a random password. Only disadvantage is you cannot use hibernate, advantage is, SWAP cannot be easily decrypted by hackers. Root/System should remain unencrypted. You can manage to auto decrypt parts of a filesystem using login/scripts, works especially well with an EXT4 filesystem, as it's supporting individual directory encryption, otherwise use encryped LUKS containers, which get auto-mounted when needed.

Comment: About automatic reboot while using LUKS. With adequate infrastructure, it's possible. See https://github.com/latchset/clevis

Comment: @paladin: thanks, I've looked it up, and that does sound like the answer. If you want to write it up I'll accept it.